# Expression must have pointer-to-struct-or-union type?

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

Working with a linked list to extract data from the head of the list. The data is already set within the Head, but when I try to access it I get that error. Think there is an issue with pointers but I cannot work it out.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;

    struct timeval start, end;
    struct element *Head = NULL;
    struct element *Tail = NULL;

    //creating job queue
    for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_JOBS; i++) {
        addLast(generateProcess(), &Head, &Tail);
    }

    //go through job queue running processes and removing processes
    while (Head) {
        runPreemptiveJob(Head->pData, &start, &end);

        int responseTime = getDifferenceInMilliSeconds(Head->pData->oTimeCreated, start);

        printf("Response Time is: %d\n", responseTime);

        Head = Head->pNext;
    }
}
```

I am expecting to be able to use the data in oTimeCreated by accessing it through the head element, which has a structure in its data field.

The error is when calling the getDifferenceInMilliSeconds function: I get an error on the Head which says "Expression must have pointer-to-struct-or-union type.

Element is shown here:

```
struct element
{
    void * pData;
    struct element * pNext;
};
```

generateProcess() returns a struct process, as defined below:

```
struct process
{
    int iProcessId;
    struct timeval oTimeCreated;
    struct timeval oMostRecentTime; 
    int iInitialBurstTime;
    int iPreviousBurstTime;
    int iRemainingBurstTime;
    int iPriority;
};
```

In the main function, generateProcess() returns a pointer to a process. This pointer is put into the linked list, and so I am trying to access the oTimeCreated variable which is part of that struct which is the head of the list.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exact error you're getting.

Comment: [mcve] please. This snippet does not contain all of the required information.

Comment: Show the declaration of `element` and any other structures it refers to.

Comment: Please make an effort and format your code properly.

Comment: It sounds like `Head->pData` is not a pointer.  It would be clear if you showed the definition of `struct element`.

Comment: I would speculate you want `Head->pData.oTimeCreated`.  But that is pure speculation.

Comment: `void` clearly is no struct or union and does not have any member `oTimeCreated`. You need to cast to the real type behing that pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is not about `Head`, it's about `Head->pData`. Pay close attention to the error message. With some compilers the error message clearly identifies a line but not the exact location within the line; if your compiler's errors aren't clear, you can get a more precise error location if you add line breaks and create more intermediate variables.

```
void *data = Head->pData;
struct timeval time_created = data->oTimeCreated;
int responseTime = getDifferenceInMilliSeconds(time_created, start);
```

Note that to write the code this way, I had to give types to the intermediate expressions `Head->pData` and `data->oTimeCreated`. To figure out what types to give, I looked at the definitions of `struct element` and `struct process`.

In particular, the type of `Head->pData` is `void*`. That's a pointer to an unspecified type. You can't dereference it, and in particular `data->oTimeCreated` results in a compilation error because `data` is not a pointer to a struct or a union. An unspecified type is not a struct or a union.

C doesn't have [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) baked into the language. It allows polymorphism, via void pointers, but like with many things in C, you need to do some of the job yourself. C does not keep track of what the actual type of an object is if you only have a void pointer to it. You have to specify when you want to dereference the pointer, and you need to get it right, otherwise [anything can happen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If you're sure that what you put in the list is a pointer to a `struct process` that's still valid, then convert or cast the void pointer to a pointer to a `struct process`. Here's an idiomatic way to do it:

```
struct process *head_process = Head->pData;
runPreemptiveJob(head_process, &start, &end);
int responseTime = getDifferenceInMilliSeconds(head_process->oTimeCreated, start);
```